# Teradata query: Subtract 1 day from a date passed as a param

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, teradata

```
SELECT start_balance FROM customer_account_details WHERE snapshot_dt = :fromDate - INTERVAL '1' DAY;
```

I have this query which I'm trying to execute via Hibernate-JPA. The `fromDate` is passed as a param and is in `LocalDate` format. I wanted to have a condition where I need the results from 1 day prior to the given date. However the query is not working. Can someone point out where the issue is?

```
Error:
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [...]
```

Comment: please post the repository class involved and the DAO class in which you are trying to execute the query

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace as well.

Comment: It’s a regular Native query using Spring data JPA.

Comment: As workaround you might use `WHERE snapshot_dt +1 = :fromDate;`, the optmizer should rewrit eit to `WHERE snapshot_dt = :fromDate - 1;`

Comment: @dnoeth Ah nice! i’ll try that. Thanks.